# Mac OS Installer Error

Tags: macos, install

I've formatted my old laptop in order to install Lion 10.7.3 version on it. During the installation process it came up with a weird looking error message, similar to the one in the next picture:

[image: Install Failed - Mac OS X could not be installed on your computer]

I'm wondering what's causing this issue and what can I do in order to solve the problem. It's a bit hard for me, a veteran Windows user, to get along with this type of OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the same issue as `format c:` failing the disk is broken

Comment: The explanation is in the error message: `damaged disk`. What's the doubt?

Comment: It worked just fine on the third try, there was nothing wrong with the disk. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message ***"Mac OS X Lion couldn't be install, because the disk Macintosh HD is damaged and can't be repaired."*** in the photo above would indicate that there is either a  problem with the physical hard drive of your Mac or the Mac's "Macintosh HD" volume is damaged at a software level.

While you're in the installer you can click on *Window > Installer* Log to view a log from the Lion installer.  This may give you some clues as to what is causing the error.  For instance, any mention of "Disk I/O Error" would be an indicator that there is a communication problem with the hard drive at a hardware level.

You can also attempt to repair the Macintosh HD volume using *Disk Utility* (should be accessible from the Lion installer's *Utility* menu), or reformat it again if the repair fails.  Once repaired or reformatted you can attempt the installation again.

Hopefully that helps.